# Arrow tip overlapping frame

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

Here are two images showing examples of what I am using in a diagram, I am giving the minimal running code just after

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning} 

\tikzstyle{fonction}=[
        align=center, line width=2pt,
        minimum width=4cm, text width=3.8cm,minimum height=1.8cm,
        rectangle,rounded corners=2pt
      ]
\tikzstyle{fonctionInfo}=[fonction, draw=black, text=black]
\tikzstyle{fleche}=[->,>=latex,line width=1mm,black]

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
        \node (Cod) at (0,0) {};
            \node[fonctionInfo,right=2.5cm of Cod] (Trai) {\LARGE Traiter \\[3mm] Mémoriser};
            \node[fonctionInfo,right=2.5cm of Trai] (Com) {\LARGE Communiquer};

                \draw[fleche,<->] (Trai.350) -- (Com.190);
                \coordinate[right=1.5cm of Com.east] (C7);
                \draw[fleche,<->] (Com.east) -- (C7); 
                \node[anchor=west,align=center] (Entree) at (C7)
                {\large Informations \\ \large issues et vers \\ \large l'exterieur};
    \end{tikzpicture} \\
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
        \node (Cod) at (0,0) {};
            \node[fonctionInfo,right=2.5cm of Cod] (Trai) {\LARGE Traiter \\[3mm] Mémoriser};
            \node[fonctionInfo,right=2.5cm of Trai] (Com) {\LARGE Communiquer};

                \draw[fleche,<->] (Trai.350) -- (Com.190) -- ++ (0.25,0cm);
                \coordinate[right=1.5cm of Com.east] (C7);
                \draw[fleche,<->] (Com.east) -- (C7); 
                \node[anchor=west,align=center] (Entree) at (C7)
                {\large Informations \\ \large issues et vers \\ \large l'exterieur};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

You can see the difference on the picture: on the second one the arrow is overlapping like I want it to. and it comes from le line :

```
\draw[fleche,<->] (Trai.350) -- (Com.190) -- ++ (0.25,0cm);
```

the end in particular the end :

```
 ++ (0.25,0cm);
```

allowing me to go a bit further with the arrow.

My first question is how can I do that for the arrows pointing to the left ?

The second question is, is there a way to have this extra length to every arrow without having to add "++ (0.25,0cm)" on each of them manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `shorten` with negative lengths, this makes the arrows longer.

```
  \draw[fleche,<->,shorten <=-0.25cm,shorten >=-0.25cm] (Trai.350) -- (Com.west|-Trai.350);
```

where `(Com.west|-Trai.350)` ensures that the arrow is horizontal. Please note also that `\tikzstyle` is deprecated, and if you set the `font` to `\Large` or `\large`, which you can also add to a style, the code becomes shorter.

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning} 

\tikzset{fonction/.style={
        align=center, line width=2pt,
        minimum width=4cm, text width=3.8cm,minimum height=1.8cm,
        rectangle,rounded corners=2pt
      },
fonctionInfo/.style={fonction, draw=black, text=black,font=\LARGE},
fleche/.style={->,>=latex,line width=1mm,black}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
        \node (Cod) at (0,0) {};
            \node[fonctionInfo,right=2.5cm of Cod] (Trai) {Traiter
            \\ M\'emoriser};
            \node[fonctionInfo,right=2.5cm of Trai] (Com) {Communiquer};

                \draw[fleche,<->] (Trai.350) -- (Com.190);
                \coordinate[right=1.5cm of Com.east] (C7);
                \draw[fleche,<->] (Com.east) -- (C7); 
                \node[anchor=west,align=center,font=\large] (Entree) at (C7)
                {Informations \\ issues et vers \\ l'exterieur};
    \end{tikzpicture} \\
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
        \node (Cod) at (0,0) {};
            \node[fonctionInfo,right=2.5cm of Cod] (Trai) {Traiter
            \\ M\'emoriser};
            \node[fonctionInfo,right=2.5cm of Trai] (Com) {Communiquer};

                \draw[fleche,<->,shorten <=-0.25cm,shorten >=-0.25cm] 
                (Trai.350) -- (Com.west|-Trai.350);
                \coordinate[right=1.5cm of Com.east] (C7);
                \draw[fleche,<->] (Com.east) -- (C7); 
                \node[anchor=west,align=center] (Entree) at (C7)
                {\large Informations \\ \large issues et vers \\ \large l'exterieur};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As always, stackexchange community delivers.

Comment: An exact answer to my problems and even some teaching corrections. Thank you.

Comment: @LMT-PhD You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

One could use `calc` to shift the coordinates of the arrow a bit

Also `tikzstyle` is deprecated and the font size changes in your nodes give incorrect spaces

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc} 

\tikzset{
    fonction/.style={
        align=center, 
        line width=2pt,
        minimum width=4cm, 
        text width=3.8cm,
        minimum height=1.8cm,
        rectangle,
        rounded corners=2pt
    },
    fonctionInfo/.style={
        fonction, 
        draw=black, 
        text=black
    },
    fleche/.style={
        ->,
        >=latex,
        line width=1mm,
        black
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\node (Cod) at (0,0) {};
\node[fonctionInfo,right=2.5cm of Cod,font=\LARGE] (Trai) {Traiter Mémoriser};
\node[fonctionInfo,right=2.5cm of Trai,font=\LARGE] (Com) {Communiquer};
\draw[fleche,<->] ($(Trai.350)+(-0.3,0)$) -- ($(Com.190)+(0.3,0)$);
\coordinate[right=1.5cm of Com.east] (C7);
\draw[fleche,<->] (Com.east) -- (C7); 
\node[anchor=west,align=center,font=\large, text width=3cm] (Entree) at (C7) {Informations issues et vers l'exterieur};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I actually thought of a way to answer the first part changing

```
\draw[fleche,<->] (Trai.350) -- (Com.190) -- ++ (0.25,0cm);
```

in

```
\draw[fleche,->] (Trai.350) -- ++ (-0.25,0cm);
\draw[fleche,->] (Trai.350) -- (Com.190) -- ++ (0.25,0cm);
```

Is there a better way ? and the second question still stands. How do I do that without some copy and paste for every arrow?